# Custom component with two-way binding

Tags: android, mvvm

Hello I am trying to create a custom component for the timepicker component with a connected text field with the time displayed.

Firstly the code i am currently using.
https://gist.github.com/KasperHelsted/ece736fec850a6f7e5c064124f3072bc

The current revision works fine as long as i only have a single `TimePicker` on the page.
But since the `mListener` has to be static, the moment i have multiple `TimePicker` the `mListener` will be overwritten by the last `Timepicker`, so only that `currentTime` is set.

If more questions you are welcome to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue.

I have done this by changing:

```
static InverseBindingListener mListener;
...
public static void setTextWatcher(View view, final InverseBindingListener textAttrChanged) {
    mListener = textAttrChanged;
}
```

To:

```
private InverseBindingListener mListener;
...
//Added this for binding the TimePicker to the two property
public void bind(InverseBindingListener mListener) {
    this.mListener = mListener;
}
...
public static void setTextWatcher(TimePicker view, final InverseBindingListener textAttrChanged) {
    view.bind(textAttrChanged);
}
```